# Border appear on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Trying to make a link display a `border-bottom` on `:hover`.

[Here is the HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/VAtD3/). When you hover on Sign In you should see a 3px border on the bottom

```
<ul class="secondaryNavList signIn">
    <li class="logo"><img src="images/layout/bbclogo.png" alt="BBC"></li>
    <li class="signin"><a href="/signin">Sign in</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the CSS for the hover

```
nav.secondary li.signIn a:hover{
    border-bottom:3px solid #0f0;
}
```

Can't seem to get this working?

Comment: `signin` check spelling in css rule, css is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

js and css are case sensitive. change `<li class="signin">` by `<li class="signIn">`

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/VAtD3/1/

Answer (score 0):

just check at the bottom of your CSS where you have:

```
nav.secondary li.signIn a:hover{
    border-bottom:3px solid #0f0;
}
```

rather use:

```
.signin:hover{
    border-bottom:3px solid #0f0;
}
```

This targets the link's class which then allows the hover action to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In your html code you have used `<ul class="secondaryNavList signIn">`

```
.secondaryNavList a:hover{
    border-bottom:3px solid #0f0;
}
```

instead of

```
nav.secondary li.signIn a:hover{
   border-bottom:3px solid #0f0;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3zP2w/**